# Adjective for someone who is an a-hole?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, pejorative-language, offensive-language, epithet-requests

I'm trying to identify an effective adjective for someone who is unpleasant to others, mean spirited, and self-centered enough to qualify as a colloquial "a$$hole".

I've looked at [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160818/adjective-that-means-someone-who-puts-people-down), but it is focused on people who are critical.  The question itself does offer **abrasive**, but it doesn't capture the sentient of universal awfulness.

I'm stuck on a neologism of **A-hole-ish** that just won't cut it.  A word that is not profane is preferable.

> That person is so _____ that they double parked in a handicap spot.

*I'm aware that the above sentence can readily be reworded to avoid the need for the adjective, but provide it as a simple use case.*

Comment: _Obnoxious_....

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but you won't find a sanitary adjective to describe an asshole. The whole point of expletives is that they describe things only generally, but with hard-hitting force. Non-profane words lessen the blow and express things more precisely. If you want a polite word, it won't describe every asshole, and, even then, it won't describe any asshole to the full extent of his assholery. But, for your example, I would suggest *inconsiderate*.

Comment: I like the connotations of _contemnable_, which looks like a variant of _condemnable_ but actually is closer in meaning to _contemptible_. It's especially satisfying (in my experience) when said in a posh accent and associated with a suitable noun such as _caitiff_ or _boor_. I should perhaps add that any such characterization is best offered from the soundproof security of one's own automobile (with the windows closed).

Comment: Perhaps a Malcontent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **odious**
>
> adjective \ˈō-dē-əs\
>
> - causing hatred or strong dislike
> - extremely unpleasant; repulsive.

Answer (score 1):

Though I absolutely loathe this word and its close relatives, in US-English I think "douchy" is used fairly frequently.

However, useful non-slang terms that could work in the example you gave might be "selfish" and "self-centred".

Comment: +1 This does nail the sentiment, but I agree that the word is rather distasteful and lacks a certain amount of sophistication.

Answer (score 1):

How about any of the following?

- contemptible
- abominable
- slimy
- scummy
- déclassé
- vile
- opprobrious
- infamous

Comment: Love opprobrious.  In keeping with the "origin" of the original suggested word, I note that fecal can be used as an adjective.  I further note that while I've never heard someone described as fecal, the sentence "That person is so fecal-like, they double parked in a handicap spot" is rather amusing.

Comment: +1 - I also am partial to opprobrious.  It prompted my memory banks for the term __odious__, which might be even better.  Will leave it open for another day to see if anything better comes along.

Answer (score 1):

- Arrogant (takes what is not his to take)
- Anti-social (cares nothing about societal conventions)
- Obnoxious (just generally disagreeable)

Pick any two from these and others' suggestions. It takes at least two non-profane pejoratives to come close to what "asshole" conveys.

Comment: Interesting comment. This equation of 2*non-profane = profane is intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

**Reprobate** might fit. It can be an adjective or a noun.

Comment: The question asks for an adjective specifically.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't yell an adjective out the car window at an Amish buggy - so a noun might still come in handy.

Comment: Adding a definition here would help readers who are unfamiliar with the term _reprobate_ and would appreciate the convenience of finding the meaning in the same place as the word suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Inconsiderate** may be a bit mild for your purposes, but it's worthy of consideration.

Comment: It's not bad, but lacks the punch and true vileness of a real a$$hole as you've noted.

Answer (score -1):

Having surveyed a particular suburb with many people like this, "jerk" is a descriptor, so is "entitled" for those who have a sense of entitlement over everyone else (not that they are inheritors, they just act imperiously). Sometimes a-hole is an emphatic suitable for a complaint context (e.g. "He's such an asshole, parking illegally like that."), but jarring in normal prose. (That person is so entitled that they double parked in a handicap spot.)